# New line after table generated with kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I'm trying to get new line after table generated by kable(), but when I use cat("\n") after generated table, then table disappears from word document created by r-markdown.

```
tab <- Framework[sample == 1 & pop_part == 3]
i <- Framework[sample == 1 & pop_part == 3,.N]
if (i!=0){
  kable(tab)
  cat("\n")
}
```

Why it is destroyed and how to get new line after kable generated table properly? Also would be great to know hoe to center kable generated table in word.

Comment: AFAIKR a single backslash is used for new lines in, within a string it must be escaped eg. `cat("\\")` ;-) I did not try, please always provide a minimal reproducible example here to make it easier for us to help!